# Angular.js+nw.js+webpack+karma+jasmine how to test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, karma-jasmine

I have a [nw.js](https://nwjs.io/) native application with [angular.js](https://docs.angularjs.org/) inside. My app bundled with webpack and contains native node.js modules. My entry point is index.js file that I organized like this:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var angular = require('angular');
require('./app.css');

// other modules

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRaven',
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngMessages'
]).constant(
    'fs', require('fs')
)

require('./services')(myApp);
require('./directives')(myApp);
require('./factories')(myApp);
require('./filters')(myApp);
require('./controllers')(myApp);
require('./app.js')(myApp);
```

My webpack config looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
    entry: [
        './app/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    target: 'node-webkit',
    module:{
        // css, html loaders
    },
    node: {
        os: true,
        fs: true,
        child_process: true,
        __dirname: true,
        __filename: true
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

So every dependency include Node.js native modules like `fs`, `path`, `child_process` bundled in one big file `bundle.js` that i include in html and then package my **nw.js** app. So my app structure looks like:

```
my_project:
--app
----controllers
------welcome
--------welcome.js // Page controller
--------welcome.html // Page HTML
------index.js // here I include each page controller
----app.js // My angular app initialization
----index.js // here I include all dependencies
```

I'm trying to run tests with this structure. I tried karma+jasmine, karma+mocha, tried different configurations, my last one looks like:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [
            'app/bundle.js',
            'app/**/*spec.js'
        ],
        exclude: [],
        preprocessors: {
            'app/bundle.js': ['webpack']
        },
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
        customLaunchers: {
            ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
                base: 'ChromeHeadless',
                flags: ['--no-sandbox']
            }
        },
        singleRun: true,

        webpack: {
            // you don't need to specify the entry option because
            // karma watches the test entry points
            // webpack watches dependencies

            // ... remainder of webpack configuration (or import)
        },

        webpackMiddleware: {
            // webpack-dev-middleware configuration
            // i.e.
            noInfo: true,
            // and use stats to turn off verbose output
            stats: {
                // options i.e.
                chunks: false
            }
        }
    });
};
```

But my tests still not see the angular application.

```
describe('Welcome page', function() {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('WelcomePageCtrl'));
});
```

**P.S** I don't require exactly `karma` and `jasminne`, so any solution will be appreciated. I just want to cover my project with tests

Comment: Have you ever run unit tests with webpack+angular+karma?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov only from angular seed: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Comment: your tag said 'e2e-testing' but you were attempting a unit-test, so I anwsered for a unit-test.

Comment: @aec I will remove tag, thanks, hope this will work. Try in few days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have gone through something similar myself. I don't think you need the `bundle.js` for your tests.

Here is how would do it:

I assume your controller/service/etc implementation is as follows:

```
    /* app/controller/welcome.js */
    module.exports = function(app) {
        return app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "lebouf";
        });
    };
```

I like my test code to sit right beside the code I'm testing (`Welcome.spec.js` in the same directory as `Welcome.js`). That test code would look like so:

```
/* app/controller/welcome.spec.js */
beforeEach(function() {
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []); //module definition
    require("./welcome")(app);
});
beforeEach(mockModule("myApp"));

describe("MyCtrl", () => {
    var scope = {};
    beforeEach(mockInject(function($controller) {
        $controller("MyCtrl", {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it("has name in its scope", function() {
        expect(scope.name).to.equal("not lebouf"); //the test will fail
    });
});
```

Except, this is an angular controller we're testing and it's not that simple. We need the `angular` object itself. So lets set it up. I'll explain why it is done how it is done next:

```
/* test-setup.js */
const jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom; //v5.6.1
const chai = require("chai");

global.document = jsdom("<html><head></head><body></body></html>", {});
global.window = document.defaultView;
global.window.mocha = true;
global.window.beforeEach = beforeEach;
global.window.afterEach = afterEach;

require("angular/angular");
require("angular-mocks");

global.angular = window.angular;
global.mockInject = angular.mock.inject;
global.mockModule = angular.mock.module;
global.expect = chai.expect;

console.log("ALL SET");
```

And we'll run the tests as:

```
node_modules/.bin/mocha ./init.js app/**/*.spec.js
#or preferably as `npm test` by copying the abev statement into package.json
```

---

extra info

Here is how `init.js` is setup as is:

1. `jsdom`: f you `require("angular/angular")` you'll see that it needs a `window` instance. `jsdom` can create `document`s and `window`s and so on without a web browser!
2. `window.mocha`: we need `angular-mocks` to populate our `angular` with the necessary utilities. But [if you look at the code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/6706353a71e3c11c56c0b19be03600dac57aafe1/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L3017) you'll notice that `window.mocha || window.jasmine` needs to be `true`. That`s why`window.mocha = true`
3. `window.beforeEach`, `window.afterEach`: the same reason as above; because `angular-mocks.js` demands it.
4. I set some global variables that I plan to use commonly in my tests: `angular`, `expect`, `mockInject`, `mockModule`.

Also these may provide some additional information:

- https://kasperlewau.github.io/post/angular-without-karma/
- https://gist.github.com/rikukissa/dcb422eb3b464cc184ae

Comment: Seems it is a right method, but I can't load nw.gui module in tests, because it loading during run time, when I do /path/to/nw /path/to/my/app

Comment: do you require nwgui from `welcome.js`? If so, I think you should take it as a function parameter, like I do with `app` in my `MyCtrl`

Comment: As described here I should run nw in new process... https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Testing

Comment: but I can't figure this out

Comment: or I should use their tool... https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-run-node-webkit%27s-test-cases

Comment: I disagree. You are unit-testing. Your controllers, if they are in the sprit of angular controllers won't be manipulating the views. Your controllers should not depend on `nw.gui`. **IF** they do, then you should take it via variable injection so you can test it easily.

Comment: By *variable injection*, I mean taking it as a parameter in `MyCtrl.js` like I did with the `app`. You can even have an angular service that requires and wraps `nw.gui`, which you can use in the rest of your angular code.

Comment: Yes, but I do this like this:
```
 var gui = require('nw.gui');
var angular = require('angular');
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRaven',
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngMessages'
]).constant(
    'gui', gui
)
```

Comment: The problem that nw.gui is only loading during runtime and can't be loaded in unit tests via `require()`

Comment: but I think it is a problem of nw.js and should be another question

Comment: Yes and you don't need your index.js or app.js for your unit tests. Have you seen how my tests run for only `*.spec.js` files. I did my module definition manually, I didn't require `app.js` to do it.

Comment: BUT you can use [mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require) if you really want to require `ng-gui`. I still think you shouldn't, and keep that code out of unit tests for your angular code.